# How to control the printwriter from a separate method?

Tags: java, socket.io

Im working on building my own GUI program that talks to my pc from a tablet. I have the server side done in java but my problem is on the client side.

I want to send data out the PrintWriter to the server from a separate method. 
I have accomplished sending in the code below (it sends 'a') but i cant figure out how to send it from a separate method. i believe its a basic java scope problem that im not understanding. i would really appreciate the help.

I have tried moving the variables into other scopes.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hostName = "192.168.0.3";
        int portNumber = 6666;

        try (   //Connect to server on chosen port.
                Socket connectedSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
                //Create a printWriter so send data to server.
                PrintWriter dataOut = new PrintWriter(connectedSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
            ) {
            //Send data to server.
            dataOut.println("a");

        }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
                hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } 
    }

    public static void sendToServer() {
        //I want to control the print writer from this method.
        //I have failed i all the ways i have tried.

    }
}
```

Comment: Try passing the `PrintWriter` as an argument to that method.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the Printer-Code (try try block) into the sendToServer-method and call it via

```
TestClient client = new TestClient();
client.sendToServer("this is a test");
```

Of course the sendToServer method needs to accept a parameter then. Even better would probably be to put the main method into a Starter class and decouple it from the Client-Class that you use for sending the data.

Comment: So its fine to try to open the socket again even if i already have it connected. it wont make things run slow or anything? i thought there would be a problem constantly asking it to connect every time i send new data.

Comment: That should be fine. Just don't forget to manually close it after sending data. You could add a "finally{}" statement to your try-catch block and call Socket.close(); from there. This will free the port for another connection, when you are sending data again.